# active input form - appearing label - pure css solution

Tags: html, css, sass

I am creating an easy form in css and I was wondering if there is a way to only use css without going for javascript or jquery class adding.

When I type in the form in the input element I want the label to appear, and I want it to appear when the user types in the input and dissaprear when they are not.

so far I was thinking to use an :active pseudo class on the input element and then set the opacity and transition to the label element. but not sure how to connect these two only with pure css not js or jquery class adding.

```
  <section class="section-book">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="book">
          <div class="book__form">
            <div class="u-margin-bottom-medium">
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">
                Start booking now
              </h2>
            </div>
            <form action="#" class="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                <label for="name" class="form__label">Full name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form__group">
                <input type="email" class="form__input" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                <label for="email" class="form__label">Email address</label>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator:

```
  label{
    opacity:0;
  }
  input:focus ~ label{
    opacity:1;
    transition:all ease-in 300ms;
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L38u2tvm/

Comment: Thanks!! :) Exactly what I was looking for!